# Count active users if they have made a buy in the last three months (Historical) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query

```
        with months (Date,Familia) as (
          select cast(eomonth(datefromparts(year(date_var),
          month(date_var),01)) as datetime) as Fecha, p.family as 'Familia'
          from sales v
          left join products p on p.id_product=v.id_product
          where date_var >= '2016-08-01'
          group by date_var, p.family
         )
select m.Date, m.Family, (
 select count(distinct v.user_id)
 from sales v
 where datediff(month, m.Date, v.date_var) between -2 and 0 and 
 v.date_var >= '2016-08-01'
 ) as 'Active Users'
from months m
group by m.family, m.Date
order by m.Date
```

I want to obtain the number of active users, taking into account that a user counts as active if they have made a purchase in the last three months.

For instance

| family | year | month | # |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nubrenza | 2017 | 1 | 2500 |
| Keppra | 2017 | 1 | 350 |
| Nubrenza | 2017 | 2 | 2400 |
| Keppra | 2017 | 2 | 357 |

Active users of January 2017 would be count( DISTINCT users) who have made a transaction in January 2017, Dec 2016 and / or Nov 2016 and so on...

**Update** my query is now showing the distinct count of users grouping them by month but it's returning the same value for all my families, how can I fix that?

Comment: So what is your question? And where is your sample data and expected results?

Comment: Its still not clear what you want? If you want 3 months change `<=3` to `<=2`? Sample data and expected results would clarify.

Comment: Do you want maybe the start of 3 months ago til now, or maybe the start of 3 months ago to the start of this month?

Comment: Better to filter `date_column >= some_function_on_current_date` instead of `some_date_diff(date_column, getdate()) <= threshold`, because the first way can use indexes, partitions and statistical information on `date_column`, while the second cannot.

Comment: I want to count the active users (if they have made any transaction in the last three months)
Example:
Active users of August 2020 would be count DISTINCT users who have made a transaction in August 2020, July 2020 and / or June 2020 and so on..
And I'm not sure if datediff works in this specific problem.

Comment: @rrctor Please, describe what is your issue? Do you have results that you expect to be different? So you need to post sample data and desired output so someone would have a chance to help. If you have a problem with 4 months instead of 3... I do not know, how to help to change the number in filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the months and use a subquery:

```
with months as (
      select convert(date, '2017-01-01') as month
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, month)
      from months
      where month < '2018-01-01'
     )
select m.month,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable t
        where datediff(month, date_var, m.month) between 0 and 2
       )
from months m;
```